# How do I configure a naked domain and a mail server to a cloud hosted app?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I have a web app with no fixed IP address:

**myapp.apps.com**

And a custom domain:

**example.com**

I have the www subdomain (www.example.com) pointing to the web app with a CNAME record.

I have the mail server hooked up with MX records (me@example.com).

What I want is to be able to hit the naked domain in the web browser (example.com).

**How do I do this?**

Bear in mind that if I point a CNAME record to the naked domain it will override the mail server settings. I have access to advanced DNS settings (A, MX, CNAME, TXT, SRV).

Comment: Please leave a comment if you mark down so I know what's wrong, cheers.

Comment: You can't do this.  Or at least you can't do this without using non-standard DNS server that interepets things on the backend.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot point `@` to `CNAME` record, so `@` must have `A` record and since you have no IP address you cannot do it, also changing `@` would not have effect on your `MX` record.

Comment: I have @ pointing to the web app with a CNAME record. It works but it overrides all other records.

Comment: @Rupert Yes - the issue isn't that it's not possible, but that if you do it, everything else will break.